# How to join three different types on a same column

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, join, linq-to-entities

I need to write a join query for the below scenario. I know how to write joins when there are tables with PRIMARY Key and other table defined it as Foreign Key. But here the case is different. Please see the structure of the table.

```
 ID      Type      UserId

 1       User         1              // Straight away defining User table
 2       Dept         10             // Defining Dept. so it should get all the users under the Dept Id(10)
 3       Route        100            // Defining Route. so it should get all the users from Route Id(100).
```

I don't know how can i write a join query for this case in LINQ. Pls suggest me anything for this.

I have tried in three different set of queries and later join those reults as a single List. Here is the code.

Code:

```
var usersWithDeptId = db.Users.Where(asd => asd.UserDeptId == Id).Select(asd => asd.Id);
var listUserValue = from cap in db.CareAllocationPercents
                    where cap.Type == 1 && UsersWithDeptId.Contains(cap.UserId)
                    select new UserWithDeptId
                    {
                         Year = db.CareAllocations.FirstOrDefault(amt => amt.CareItemId == cap.CareItemId).Year,
                         Amount = db.CareAllocations.FirstOrDefault(amt => amt.CareItemId == cap.CareItemId).Amount,
                         UserId = cap.UserId,
                         UserDeptId = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(userdept => userdept.Id == cap.UserId).UserDeptId,
                         Percentage = cap.Percentage,
                         CareItemId = cap.CareItemId,
                         Category = "User",
                         CareAllocationId = cap.Id
                    };
listUserValue = listUserValue.Where(asd => asd.Year == Year).ToList();

List<int> routeIds = db.CareAllocationPercents.Where(asd => asd.Type == 3).Select(asd => asd.UserId).ToList();
var UsersWithRoutingId = from route in db.RoutingListMembers
                         where RouteIds.Contains(route.RoutingListId.Value) && route.User.UserDeptId == Id
                         select new RoutingWithUser
                         {
                             UserId = route.UserId,
                             RoutingId = route.RoutingListId
                         };

var listRouteValue = from cap in db.CareAllocationPercents
                     where cap.Type == 3
                     select new UserWithDeptId
                     {
                          Year = db.CareAllocations.FirstOrDefault(amt => amt.CareItemId == cap.CareItemI).Year,
                          Amount = db.CareAllocations.FirstOrDefault(amt => amt.CareItemId == cap.CareItemI).Amount,
                          UserId = cap.UserId,
                          UserDeptId = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(userdept => userdept.Id == cap.UserId).UserDeptId,
                          Percentage = cap.Percentage,
                          Category = "Route",
                          CareItemId = cap.CareItemId,
                          CareAllocationId = cap.Id
                     };

List<UserWithDeptId> newRouteList = new List<UserWithDeptId>();
ListRouteValue = listRouteValue.Where(asd => asd.Year == Year).ToList();

foreach (var listdept in ListRouteValue)
{
    var user = UsersWithRoutingId.FirstOrDefault(uwri => uwri.RoutingId == listdept.UserId);
    if (user != null)
    {
        NewRouteList.Add(new UserWithDeptId
            {
                UserId = user.UserId,
                Year = listdept.Year,
                UserDeptId = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(asd => asd.Id == user.UserId).Select(asd => asd.UserDeptId),
                Percentage = listdept.Percentage,
                CareItemId = listdept.CareItemId,
                Amount = listdept.Amount,
                CareAllocationId = listdept.CareAllocationId,
                Category = listdept.Category });
    }
}

newRouteList = newRouteList.Where(asd => asd.UserDeptId == Id).ToList();
var listUserId = from user in db.Users
                 where user.UserDeptId == Id
                 select new UserWithDeptId
                 {
                      UserId = user.Id
                 };

var listDeptId = from cap in db.CareAllocationPercents
                 where cap.Type == 2 && cap.UserId == Id
                 select new UserWithDeptId
                 {
                      Year = db.CareAllocations.FirstOrDefault(amt => amt.CareItemId == cap.CareItemId).Year,
                      Amount = db.CareAllocations.FirstOrDefault(amt => amt.CareItemId == cap.CareItemId).Amount,
                      UserDeptId = cap.UserId,
                      Percentage = cap.Percentage,
                      Category = "Dept",
                      CareItemId = cap.CareItemId,
                      CareAllocationId = cap.Id,
                 };

listDeptId = listDeptId.Where(asd => asd.Year == Year).ToList();
List<UserWithDeptId> newList = new List<userWithDeptId>();

foreach (var listdept in listDeptId)
{
    foreach (var users in listUserId)
    {
        newList.Add(new UserWithDeptId
            {
                UserId = users.UserId,
                UserDeptId = listdept.UserDeptId,
                Percentage = listdept.Percentage,
                CareItemId = listdept.CareItemId,
                Amount = listdept.Amount,
                CareAllocationId = listdept.CareAllocationId,
                Category = listdept.Category
            });
    }
}
newList.AddRange(listUserValue);
newList.AddRange(newRouteList);
```

Comment: What for do you move `Where()` from main query (in query syntax) to external query (in extension method syntax)? Makes no sense.